# Warning: Undefined variable issue

Tags: php

> Warning: Undefined variable $Name in D:\coding\New folder\htdocs\Mp\pdf.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in D:\coding\New folder\htdocs\Mp\fpdf184\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 D:\coding\New folder\htdocs\Mp\fpdf184\fpdf.php(1060): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 D:\coding\New folder\htdocs\Mp\fpdf184\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 D:\coding\New folder\htdocs\Mp\pdf.php(20): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in D:\coding\New folder\htdocs\Mp\fpdf184\fpdf.php on line 271

my line 18 looks like

```
$pdf->Cell(50,10,$Name,1,0);
```

Comment: This is just another way to say `headers already sent`.

Comment: @HonkderHase The warning causes the error. Those aren't the same thing. Resolving the warning likely would resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to print out something on the screen before using FPDF->Output().

Can you try removing FPDF->Output(), and see if you get a blank white page?